# DataStax DDC Service will not start

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have just installed DataStax Community Edition but when trying to run the following command;

```
C:\> net start DataStax_DDC_Server
```

I get the following response:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Does your system.log contain any exceptions?

Comment: Hi Aaron. The system.log does not have any errors no.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I ran into the same issue myself.

Try the following:

Open the cassandra.yaml file which can be found at 
C:\INSTALLPATH\apache-cassandra\conf

1. Open the cassandra.yaml file and press Ctrl + F and look for     **`#cdc_raw_directory:`**
2. Uncomment the line by removing the "#" symbol and replace the contents with the following: 
   **`"C:/INSTALLPATH/data/cdc_raw"`**

So your full line should look like: 
`cdc_raw_directory: "C:/Program Files (x86)/DataStax Community/data/cdc_raw"`

Save the file and your service should start now :)

Comment: You should re-start a cassandra server and then the CQL-shell.

Comment: Thanks Jpnathan, it works.     cdc_raw_directory: "C:/DataStax-DDC/data/cdc_data"

Answer (score 2):

I installed datastax cassandra on my D drive in windows 10 as D:\datastax, got the same error but I had to update all paths in D:\datastax\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra.yaml like this :

hints_directory: D:\datastax\data\hints
data_file_directories:
    - D:\datastax\data\data
commitlog_directory: D:\datastax\commitlog
cdc_raw_directory: D:\datastax\data\cdc_raw
saved_caches_directory: D:\datastax\saved_caches